# python/mongoengine passing keyword argument as variable

Tags: python, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I am trying to create a get method that passes key/value arguments to fetch objects.

```
def find_by_one(self, val, key='id'):
    obj = self.__model__.objects(key=val).first()
    return obj if obj else None
```

Error I get

```
InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "key"
```

kindall answered my question. I ended up altering my method to pass **kwargs and passing this as my queryset

```
  def find_by_one(self, **kwargs):
    user = self.__model__.objects(**kwargs).first()
    return user if user else None
```

now I can just call my find_by_one

```
obj.find_by_one(id=obj_id)
```

instead of

```
obj.find_by_one(obj_id)
```

Comment: That's a good solution, too. If you want to provide an even easier way to query by a particular field, you could just have a `find_by_id` or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that your model does not have a field named `key`, which is what it's looking for because you are passing in `key=val`.

I'm assuming that you're looking for `key` to be replaced by the value of the `key` argument to the function. Keyword arguments do not work this way, so in this case you'll need to construct a dictionary and use unpacking:

```
obj = self.__model__.objects(**{key: val}).first()
```